# Attendance column not showing up as field when creating new calendar item (SP2010)

Tags: calendar

I have a SharePoint calendar, with a little over a dozen columns (I have also added a couple extra columns). When adding/editing calendar events, I notice that the Attendance column is not showing up as a field. If I look in SP Designer, I see the column, Attendance, but it shows a blank Content Type (whereas most all the other columns have a Content Type of Event). Can someone please talk me through this? Not only do I need the Attendance column to be a field for a calendar event, but I have the same calendar on many other sites, so hopefully I can update the Content Type for the Attendance column to Event and solve my problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

The process to add an Attendee column is:

Go to List Settings and click on Event in the Content Type section. Then click on "Add from existing site or list columns". Choose Attendee from the list columns and click on Add.

You can also select “use this calendar to share member’s schedule” in List Settings/Title, Description and Navigation. A new content type "Schedule" will be added , which contains the Attendee field.